# Identify if a user is online in Google Hangout

Tags: google-hangouts

How can I know if a user is online or offline in Google Hangout? In the Hangout on Gmail web it shows a green line under the user's profile pic. But there no such thing in Android app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just released today, version 1.2 says this in the "What's new" section:

> - You can finally see who is on Hangouts! When you start a new Hangout, green icons show who's on, and gray shows who's not.

Also of note:

> - Contacts are now organized by People you Hangout with, Suggested People, and Other Contacts.
> - Long press contacts in the New Hangout screen to hide them.

Answer (score 2):

Hangouts doesn’t use the green or grey dots that Google Talk used to identify if someone is online or offline. Instead, you can tell **if a contact is online or not  if their profile picture is clear or faded**. A faded profile picture means your contact is unavailable, and a clear picture means they’re online. One downside is that Hangouts doesn’t support the “invisible” status like Google Talk did

Comment: Well, it does show some contacts faded in Hangouts Android app. But they don't match the contacts which show with green line under the photos of online contacts in Hangouts with Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the user has the Gmail webapp open and what platform you are using.  As September 2014's version 2.3.757 on Android, here's the breakdown

If they person is...

On Gmail Webapp or Chrome Extension Open
They appear online in all places

- Webapp/Extension is open, but not active [GChat "busy"] - they appear online everywhere, but you cannot see their device
- active recently in Hangouts [Gchat "online"] - online and can see device
- conversation open - online, can see device, and bolded avatar

Only on a Mobile App [Gchat "away"]
You will see no status icon in Gmail

- not active recently in mobile app - online, but you cannot see device
- active recently in Hangouts mobile app - online AND you can see device
- conversation open - online, can see device, and bolded avatar

Answer (score 1):

If the user is offline, their tiny picture that sits in the chat is faded.